# Can I reenter Schengen via a different country than the one for which I hold a residency card?

Tags: schengen, sweden, iranian-citizens, german-residents

I'm from Iran and am a student in Germany where I have a residency card. I want to go home and return but, rather than to Germany, direct to Sweden from Iran, to visit my friend.

It is possible or not?

Comment: To the close voters: This is not a question for Expats -- it is specifically a question about making a short visit to Sweden, the kind of travel that is on topic here. The fact that the asker happens to live in a country other than his nationality doesn't mean that he can't or shouldn't ask about his pleasure travel away from that place on this site.

Answer (score 6):

It is perfectly possible. My friend from India entered Europe through Paris even though he was a student in Germany. As your visa is student national visa, it allows multiple entries into the Schengen area and you are perfectly fine. But it is always safe to have a ticket from Sweden to Germany if you have already booked it.

Comment: +1, but a residency card is implicitly multi-entry :)

Comment: Yeah you are right. Did not read it properly.